# A better IDE for java EE development with Tomcat than Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, netbeans

At this point, I've pretty much had it with Netbeans. I can't seem to get it to work with Tomcat out of the box. Even downloading Tomcat and adding it to Netbeans doesn't work - I keep getting a pop-up asking for authentication, which I enter but yet it comes back again and again and again. Looked all over the internet for an answer, but everything just leads to nowhere.
Can anyone recommend a better IDE? I know of Eclipse, but I've never used it before. Is that any better than Netbeans?

Thanks.

Comment: "In my opinion, the IDE is rubbish." This wil get your question closed as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also suggest Eclipse, I've used it a for long time and never had issues with it.

Currently on my current job, we are using IBM's Rational Software Architect for WebSphere, which is basically Eclipse under an IBM name with some customizations for WebSphere (and a huge price tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Eclipse(https://www.eclipse.org/) or IntelliJ IDEA comminity Edition (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Answer (score 0):

**Can anyone recommend a better IDE?**
There is no such thing as a better IDE, the answer to that is opinion based.All IDEs have their pros and cons.
That said, there is a special `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` You can download it at the official eclipse [website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)